# RecyclerView внутри ScrollView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Мне нужно разместить слайдер (на основе ViewPager) и поле него список записей (RecyclerView).
Я получил вот такую разметку для этого:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="260dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top">
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/slider_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            <media.nevsky.apost.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/slider_indicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:paddingLeft="22dp"
                android:paddingRight="22dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

И вроде работает, но проблема в том что не работают события скрола ( RecyclerView.OnScrollListener) у RecyclerView.
А у меня по нему подгрузка новых записей происходит.
Пробовал использовать вместо ScrollView NestedScrollView но безуспешно.
Можно ли заставить работать RecyclerView.OnScrollListener в таких условиях?

Используемые библиотеки:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит RecyclerView вводить дочерним от ScrollView так как он при необходимости может сам скролить. Лучше пересмотреть разметку например таким образом: ScrollView убрать, вместо FrameLayout попробовать RelativeLayout.

Comment: Да, тогда слайдер перестанет скролиться а RecyclerView будет, но это не то что нужно, все должно скролиться целой страницей